# React Native - updating state between navigation screen components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I’m new to React Native and I’ve come across a problem that I can’t seem to overcome, even though on the face of it, seems pretty simple. I’m developing an app that utilises Google API location services and react navigation.

I have two components that are grouped within a stackNavigator. Component A holds a location state and I want Component B (which is a geolocation picker screen utilising asynchronous API calls) to generate location data dependent on user choice, and to push this data to Component A and update its state.

My problem lies in updating the state on Component A in that the returned object from B is undefined.

Hope some kind soul can help!

```
//COMPONENT A
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({})
    useFocusEffect(useCallback(
        () => {
                const getNewLocation = () => {
                    const location = {
                        name: props.navigation.getParam('name'),
                        latitude: props.navigation.getParam('latitude'),
                        longitude: props.navigation.getParam('longitude')
                    }
                    return location
                }
                setLocation(getNewLocation())

        }, []
    ))
    return (
        <ScrollView style={style.homeContainer}>{location.name}</ScrollView>
    )


//COMPONENT B
    const handleLocationSelect = async (text) => {
        const coordsObject = await getCoordsFromString(text)
        const {results: [{geometry: {location: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}}}]} = coordsObject
        props.navigation.navigate('Home',
            {
                name: text,
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude
            }    
        )
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={style.container}>
            <Text style={style.header}>Choose a location - more coming soon!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => handleLocationSelect('Brighton, UK')}>
                <Text style={style.location}>Brighton</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
.......................................
.......................................
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether Component A has a route "Home" so I assume it does. In order to get the navigation props, you can use the `useNavigation()` hook in "Home", i.e

```
const nav = useNavigation();
const location = nav.getParam("location");
```

I am not sure why you need useFocusEffect and useCallback, these are rather useful for long-running operations, while you just seem to pass arguments synchronously.

If your navigation tree is getting big, you might want to consider using Redux to hold a central state.

Comment: Component A is the Home screen actually, and it does have the navigation props :) I'm using useFocusEffect because its the only way I can figure out how to change some text (derived from the updated state) when I navigate back to this screen from Component B. Hope i'm making sense..

Comment: If it does have the navigation props, what is the problem?Just for clarity, when you are using navigation.navigate(), you are not really moving back, you are adding a new screen to the stack.

Comment: In Component A the properties are coming back undefined, but when I console.log everything in B, the properties are populated correctly.. I'm not sure if it's something to do with the fact I'm making async calls from B